# PHP exec() command: execute in a specified directory

Tags: php, exec, directory-structure

I have the following code:

```
chdir('../certs');

    file_put_contents('input.csr', $csr);

    exec("openssl req -in input.csr -noout -out output.txt -text");
    $outputFile = file_get_contents("output.txt");

    unlink('input.csr');
    unlink('output.txt');

chdir('../home');
```

Is there a way i can specify the execution directory in the `exec()` directory as opposed to changing directories to `/certs` and back (to `/home`)?

I've tried:

```
exec("cd ../certs; openssl req -in input.csr -noout -out output.txt -text");
```

Which doesn't work. (I'm guessing that wouldn't change the directory back either?).

Comment: I think the `cd` should work. But it looks like you got the name wrong, it should be `../certs`, not `../keys`.

Comment: Can you try using chdir('Full_path') instead of chdir('../home') or chdir('../certs')?

Comment: `openssl req -in /path/to/input.csr -noout -out /path/to/output.txt` would do as well, without having to mess around with changing directories

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. @MarcB Will try full paths and see if it works.